# Continues function expression for a special piecewise function in signal processing

Tags: function, continuous, piecewise

When I do the signal processing, I have a special piecewise function:

```
f(x) = 1 if x > 1;
f(x) = x if 0 <= x <= 1;
f(x) = 0 if x < 0 ;
```

If there any continuous function that could approximately express this piecewise function, where it is continuous differentiable for any x?

Answer (score 1):

[image: formula]

epsilon = positive constant near zero